# How to "redirect" from one domain to another inside a container?

Tags: docker

I have a container, and I need that if inside the container I request "internal-network-example.com" (available only inside a local network), it is converted to "external-network-example.com" (available on the Internet).

I cannot use the "hosts" method because it just changes de IP, and when the server receives the request with an internal domain, it won't understand it because it doesn't have that domain associated.

## Why do I need this behavior?

I'm requesting a SOAP service that is requiring some XML files. I can access the main WSDL document from an external network, but the XML file URLs are written with the internal URL, so PHP fails to parse those URLs. If those URLs were written with the external URL, it would work.

Comment: It is a bit hard to understand the flow of requests, and where it fails. Try describe it point by point and where the trouble starts, as a sequence diagram or similar.

Comment: This isn't any different running in Docker; do the exact same thing you'd do if you weren't running this in containers (at a low level, send an HTTP 301 or 302 response).  The best thing to do would be to fix the URL in the WSDL file itself, or the tool that generates it, but Docker on its own is incapable of rewriting XML content or other HTTP message bodies.